# Cant open serial monitor on linux

Tags: serial, linux, arduino-pro-micro

I have a pro micro and I'm running the IDE on linux.
The IDE easily recognises that my board is on /dev/ttyACM0 so i can flash programs on to it.
I am testing the following code

```cpp
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);     // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.print("Hello universe ");  
}
```

After I upload the code if I try to bring up the serial monitor I get this error message

> Error opening serial port '/dev/ttyACM0'. (Port busy)

tried resetting the pro micro, rebooting the computer, tried the code

> sudo usermod -a -G dialout yourUserName as suggested [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=129647.0)

But the problem still didn't solve. Any idea what went wrong.

Edit1:

I noticed that when the arduino is in the bootloader mode (i.e when I press reset) lsusb shows

> Bus 004 Device 055: ID 2341:0037 Arduino SA

however, when it starts to execute the program from its memory, lsusb doesn't show that entry. but instead, shows

> Bus 004 Device 054: ID 1b4f:9206

Comment: Modem manager. Every time.

Comment: I tried changing the USB cable. IT doesn't seem to be the cause . also check out the edit1.

Comment: To expand on Majenko's comment, try `sudo apt-get purge modemmanager`.

Comment: Thankyou Edgar Bonet your solution worked. Will you please write it as a solution, also please explain why modemmanager gave the problem. wouldnt uninstalling modemmanager trouble other apps that use it?

Comment: This solution worked for me too. I could upload sketches to my arduino via a sparkfun FTDI connector (FT231X) but could not use the serial monitor.